# Namespaces with classes and structs?

Tags: d, oop

Will be nice if I got 'nested members' in D language, so I have the inglorious idea to code

```
class Keyboard
{
    struct  Unused {
        string key1 = "Wake Up";
        string key2 = "Sleep";
        string key3 = "Power";
    }

    Unused unused;
}

int main()
{
    Keyboard kb;
    kb.unused.key1 = "Scroll Lock";

    return 0;
}
```

Okay, it's a bad example that segfault too. But I'm learning object-oriented programming and don't know if it's a good thing to do, or how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with doing that *per se*, the problem here is that `kb` is still `null`. You need to create a `Keyboard` object:

```
Keyboard kb = new Keyboard();
```

If you don't want to type `Keyboard` twice, you can use `auto`:

```
auto kb = new Keyboard();
```

And D will automatically determine the correct type for you.

It's fairly common practice to group related objects together like that into a struct, although usually you'll want a more descriptive name than `Unused` (otherwise, why have the namespace?).

Comment: It's a shame! Has some difference on running program from auto to Keyboard, or is the same thing once compiled?

Comment: It's exactly the same: the compiler can see that `new Keyboard()` returns a `Keyboard` at compile time and just adds the type itself. There is no difference in the compiled code.

Comment: @pslacerda, it is called type inference and used everywhere in D. foreach(w; words), sort(words); Even sort here has inference. The full length tho call it would be sort!(immutable(char)[][], "a < b")(words)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the syntax you first suggested. Just make unused a static member. This works fine:

```
class Keyboard
{
    struct Unused {
         string key1 = "Wake Up";
         string key2 = "Sleep";
         string key3 = "Power";
    }

    static Unused unused;   // **This is now a static member**
}

int main()
{
    Keyboard kb;
    kb.unused.key1 = "Scroll Lock";

    return 0;
}
```