# Can I avoid polluting the public namespace with D imports?

Tags: namespaces, d

It seems like there is no easy way to prevent D's import statements from clouding the global namespace:

```d
module x;    
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    writeln("Hello!");
}
```

As soon as you `import std.stdio`, `writeln` is now global. Coming from `[language with namespaces]`, it would be nice if I could only reference `std.stdio.writeln`, especially so in a week or two I can easily tell what provides `writeln`.

After reading [Namespaces with classes and structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3861160/4532996), it seems to me that this should do what I'd like (as unwieldly as it is):

```d
module x;
import std.stdio;

class String {
  struct write {
    auto println = writeln;
  }
}

void main() {
  String string = new String();
  string.write.println("Hello!");
}
```

But I get `Error: variable [...] type void is inferred from initialiser [...], and variables cannot be of type void`, which means function aliasing is out.

Were I writing C, I could understand the lack of namespaces (but I could still achieve them with structs and dot-notation). Is there any way to get imported names to not be so global?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm inclined to agree with @weltensturm -- D handles conflicts gracefully, and
artificially creating namespaces is only likely to confuse things.

One of the nice parts of D (IMHO) is avoiding those long names you see in other
languages without worrying that something terrible will happen.

However, if you really need to, take a look at the docs on
[modules](http://dlang.org/spec/module.html), which show how you can rename a module:

```
import io = std.stdio;

void main()
{
    io.writeln("hello!");        // ok, calls std.stdio.writeln
    std.stdio.writeln("hello!"); // error, std is undefined
    writeln("hello!");           // error, writeln is undefined
}
```

You can also use a static import so you are forced to use the fully qualified name:

```
static import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    std.stdio.writeln("hello!"); // OK
    writeln("hello!");           // error, writeln is undefined
}
```

Comment: Just remembered that `static import` is a thing. That may be what you're looking for.

Comment: oops, didn't realize you answered that at the time I edited. Your answer is probably better because it cuts right to the chase :)

Answer (score 5):

It is fairly simple - If you do not like namespace pollution, then you must do **static import**.

Here is what the D specification says (http://dlang.org/spec/module.html , section "Static Imports"):

> Basic imports work well for programs with relatively few modules and imports. If there are a lot of imports, name collisions can start occurring between the names in the various imported modules. One way to stop this is by using static imports. A static import requires one to use a fully qualified name to reference the module's names:

Example:

```
static import std.stdio;

void main() {
  writeln("hello!");           // error, writeln is undefined
  std.stdio.writeln("hello!"); // ok, writeln is fully qualified
}
```

If my code needs only one or two symbols from a module, I use the selective import as mentioned by Max Alibaev. Say I will use writeln() a lot. - Then I will most likely have a line `import std.stdio : writeln;` in my D code.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for *Selective Imports* (can be found on http://dlang.org/spec/module.html)?

```d
import std.stdio : writeln;
```

Comment: That's interesting but `writeln` is still globally declared and doesn't force me to use `std.stdio.writeln`

Comment: What's the purpose of this, anyways? It seems I can still get at `std.stdio.write` even if I only `import std.stdio : writeln;`

Comment: @cat It's a bug that std.stdio.write is accessible when you've selectively imported writeln. AFAIK, selective imports have never worked correctly ( https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=314 ). However, it should be fixed in the 2.071 when it's released, since there have been a number of import related fixes that have already made it into master, including for that bug specifically.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your example is that you are calling writeln, not taking its pointer. Try `&writeln`. You should also declare it as `static`, so you won't have to instantiate the namespace. (A class with only static functions in D acts pretty much like a namespace). But you should avoid artificially creating namespaces, since D handles conflicts very well and it would only increase the typing needed.

As for D's import system: every name in an imported module is made available in the current one. But as soon as you import a module with conflicting names you will be forced to use the full name anyway.

Comment: "*calling writeln*" Don't I need parentheses to do that?

Comment: @cat [parentheses are optional](http://dlang.org/spec/function.html#optional-parenthesis)